# How to install WICD on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.04, wicd

I am using ubuntu 20.04 focal 64bit. 
Pre installed network manager is giving me headache. It suddenly drops wifi connection.
On scanning again it shows no visible network.
The input command

```
lshw -C network
```

gives output

```
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
```

while searching for the solution i saw WICD solves the problem but how do i install on my laptop.
INPUT

```
sudo apt install wicd
```

OUTPUT

```
E: package 'wicd' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: i recently swiched to ubuntu i am a newbie. I liked it very much. Only the wifi drop is giving me problems

Comment: Mind that it probably is smarter to fix your problem, The drop of the connection can be because your router is not configured correctly.It could be the channel you are using. If that is the case wicd will not be the solution regardless of what online is stated.

Answer (score 5):

The `wicd-gtk` was removed from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repositories because of Python 2 deprecation.

But you still can install it if you download packages manually [from 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/wicd-gtk):

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb # second time for correct configuration
```

and then use it.

Comment: And people ask me why I prefer appimage... This is exactly what I want appimage or flatpak for

Comment: Problem: Can't install those packets

Comment: Solution: install on 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Do we need to uninstall NetworkManager and/or network-manager if we get wicd? If so, should it be removed before or after installing wicd (or does it matter)?