# Unable to install WICD network manager

Tags: networking, apt, network-manager, 20.10, wicd

I was having issues like both Wifi and Ehthernet connection is getting disconnected suddenly. So, I searched about the problem in google and found [this post about fixing the issues i'm having](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030653/wifi-randomly-disconnected-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) I tried the best to follow the post and comments to fix my issue but it didn't fixed my issue then at a point I came to a comment saying that uninstalling GNOME's Network Manager and installing WICD network manager can solve the issue and also he shared the command to install the WICD network manager but these command didn't worked just cause the commands were usable in Ubuntu 18.04 or older than that.

I came to realize reading [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240154/how-to-install-wicd-on-ubuntu-20-04?) that wicd was removed from the repositories because of Python 2 deprecation. After that I followed the post which is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240154/how-to-install-wicd-on-ubuntu-20-04?) and tried to install the WICD by downloading the packages and installing manually there was these commands

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb # second time for correct configuration
```

to install WICD manually I ran all command but at last when I ran the command `sudo apt-get install ./*.deb` the terminal looks like this

```
lmao@lol:~/Downloads/wicd$ sudo apt-get install ./*.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-glade2' instead of './python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'python-gtk2' instead of './python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb'
Note, selecting 'python-wicd' instead of './python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb'
Note, selecting 'wicd-daemon' instead of './wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb'
Note, selecting 'wicd-gtk' instead of './wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3) but it is not installable
 wicd-daemon : Depends: python-dbus but it is not installable
               Depends: python-gobject-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and I don't know how to fix the issue.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error output means that you need more dependencies to be installed manually on Ubuntu 20.10 for `wicd`:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

# for 20.10
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dbus-python/python-dbus_1.2.16-1build1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb # second time for correct configuration
```

Comment: I successfully installed WICD thank you for helping me out. But I got a little problem that is after I installed the WICD there is no tray icon associated with WICD searched online found that dconf-editor can help me fix that but it didn't the solution I tried was this.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/69005/wicd-tray-icon-doesnt-show?rq=1