# USB WiFi adapter issues

Tags: wireless, 20.04, wifi-hardware-switch

The laptop is: SONY VAIO VGN-CR490

The adapter is: TP-LINK Archer T2U AC600 v3

It is recognized:

`rfkill list all`

```
mike@mike-VGN-CR490E:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`rfkill unblock all` or `rfkill unblock wifi` is not helping.

The menu says `USB WiFi hardware disabled`

The problem is that my PCI board is kinda broken and always stays at `WIRELESS OFF`
If I switch it `ON` (I have to hold it at position `ON`) both WiFi's (PCI and USB) is going to work.

So I need USB adapter to be kinda independent from hardware switch. How can I do that?

There’s no hard nor soft blocks on the USB adapter. But it still doesn’t work as long as hardware switch is at `OFF`

`iwconfig` shows 2 devices (one PCI and one USB obviously).

Using `ifconfig PCI-wifi up` gives an error `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`

Using `ifconfig USB-wifi up` gives nothing USB WiFi remains off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sorted. Sorta big adventure, but I did it.
Based on this: [How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error/155283#155283)

And we need WICD for that. The manual to install WICD on Ubuntu 20.04 I found over here: [How to install WICD on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240154/how-to-install-wicd-on-ubuntu-20-04)

So step by step:
Installing WICD (maybe available somewhere else, but I used this way via terminal):

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb # second time for correct configuration
```

And then I uninstalled default network manager since it's not working and just messing around. And WICD does the job just fine.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager`

Once again: my issue was that the hardware switch (`WIRELESS ON/OFF`) is broken (always OFF) and was disabling my USB WiFi Adapter. And to bypass this I have to use WICD.