# ./configure: No such file or diectory

Tags: 20.04

I downloaded a **wicd-1.7.4.tar.gz** file and I changed directory  `cd Downloads` to the **.tar.gz** file and extracted it using `tar xvzf wicd-1.7.4.tar.gz`. Thereafter, I changed directory to `cd wicd-1.7.4` which is the extracted files directory. Suprisingly, when I used the command, `./configure` inside the same directory, the error I got was, **bash: ./configure: No such file or directory**. Please can someone tell me what is it that I am not doing right! Thanks
The output of the `$ ~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.4` is

````
wicd-1.7.4/NEWS
wicd-1.7.4/cli/
wicd-1.7.4/cli/README.cli
wicd-1.7.4/cli/wicd-cli.py
wicd-1.7.4/man/
wicd-1.7.4/man/nl/
wicd-1.7.4/man/nl/wicd-client.1
wicd-1.7.4/man/wicd-client.1
wicd-1.7.4/INSTALL
wicd-1.7.4/AUTHORS
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/eap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wep-passphrase
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/psu
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/peap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa2-peap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/leap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa-psk-hex
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wep-shared
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa-psk
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa-peap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/active
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/eap-tls
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/active_wired
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wired_8021x
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wpa2-leap
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/peap-tkip
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/wep-hex
wicd-1.7.4/encryption/templates/ttls
wicd-1.7.4/in/
wicd-1.7.4/in/init=pld=wicd.in```
````

Comment: The output from `ll ~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.4/INSTALL` might be where configure command is located. It's certainly not in the directory listing shown.

Comment: The ```.../INSTALL``` is a text file and not executable

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve exactly? WICD is NO solution for anything.

Comment: Read the INSTALL, and see how to build it.  python setup.py configure seems to be the starting point, but beware of all the dependencies (PYTHON2!!).

Comment: Beware that wicd appears unmaintained, and requires Python 2 (which is also unmaintained). Installation may be more challenging than you'd like, and there's no security support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install WICD on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240154/how-to-install-wicd-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 5):

Installing from repositories might be an easier method. However it was dropped from the 20.04 repository as this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240175/307523) states. The answer is replicated below.

The `wicd-gtk` was removed from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repositories because of Python 2 deprecation.

But you still can install it if you download packages manually [from 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/wicd-gtk):

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/wicd
cd ~/Downloads/wicd

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.4+tb2-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb # second time for correct configuration
```

and then use it.

Comment: thanks for your response; however, I downloaded it manually because I knew it was no longer in Ubuntu 20.04 repository. It's the download that is in ```.tar.gz``` file before I extracted.

Comment: I've tested your method in VirtualBox (Ubuntu 20.04). It works but I had two time this message box after installation : `System program problem detected`. And a few errors during installation. However the software start with the command `wicd-gtk`.

Comment: @Gounou You can try the other answer. It sounds like the author really knows his stuff.

Comment: @Gounou thanks but did you extract and run the same command ``` ./configure``` as I did in the wicd-1.7.4 directory?

Comment: ```Frenzy@Frenzy-ThinkPad-T420:~/Downloads$ cd wicd-1.7.4
Frenzy@Frenzy-ThinkPad-T420:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.4$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
Frenzy@Frenzy-ThinkPad-T420:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.4$ sudo ./configure
[sudo] password for Frenzy: 
sudo: ./configure: command not found
Frenzy@Frenzy-ThinkPad-T420:~/Downloads/wicd-1.7.4$ ls
AUTHORS  data  images   man  PKG-INFO   setup.py      wicd
CHANGES  encryption  in  MANIFEST.in  po       tests
cli   gtk    INSTALL  NEWS  README     uninstall.sh
curses   icons    LICENSE  other   setup.cfg  vcsinfo.py```

Comment: @Frenzy  It won't work with  ./configure. I've only tested the method from WinEunuuchs2Unix. My comment is under is answer. If you really want to work with the wicd-1.7.4 directory extracted from the archive you will have to use python 2 and a method similar to the one I found on linuxfromscratch.org. Did you look at alternatives for wicd actively maintained?

Comment: @Gounou yea, the NetworkManager in my ubuntu keeps logging my system off the internet eact time I try to work with my emulator on the system. I read from other suggestions that **wicd** is better that is why I am trying to install it for my work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `wicd` with python 2 if you want to install from the tar archive. The file to start the installation with is `setup.py`.

First you have to install the dependencies. I think it is better if you create a virtual environment for python. Maybe you can look at alternatives actively maintained or use the method from *WinEunuuchs2Unix*.

Source for the installation and complete (?) instructions :
https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.2/basicnet/wicd.html. Don't know if it's similar with Ubuntu 20.04. I think it won't be easy.

**Required**

Python-2.7.14, D-Bus Python-1.2.6, Wireless Tools-29, and Net-tools-CVS_20101030 (Wicd needs mii-tool from this package)

**Recommended**

PyGTK-2.24.0 (for the GTK frontend), wpa_supplicant-2.6 (for WPA support), and dhcpcd-7.0.1 or DHCP-4.4.0 (for DHCP support)

**Optional**

pm-utils-1.4.1 (for suspend/resume integration), Urwid (for the Curses-based frontend), and Babel (for internationalization)